# PSRemoting fails through VPN

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

My laptop is domain joined and I use PSRemoting just fine from my office. I get an error when trying to connect outside the office via VPN. I have triple checked our firewall but the issue seems to be with the client or server since "Test-WSMan" succeeds with no issues. I have added the machines to each others' trust hosts and try many other things with no success. Please help!

I am a member of Domain Admins and the laptop is on the domain.

```
Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server SERVERNAME failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
process the request. The following error with errorcode 0x80090311 occurred while using Kerberos authentication: The
are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.
  -Kerberos accepts domain user names, but not local user names.
  -The Service Principal Name (SPN) for the remote computer name and port does not exist.
  -The client and remote computers are in different domains and there is no trust between the two domains.
 After checking for the above issues, try the following:
  -Check the Event Viewer for events related to authentication.
  -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM TrustedHosts configuration setting or
use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command: winrm help config. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession SERVERNAME
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SERVERNAME:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Answer (score 0):

From the issue, my understandings are as follows:

- While adding the trusted hosts, you should add the servers with FQDN like

> Set-Item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value Server01.Domain01.Fabrikam.com

- During Enter-PSSession, I would recommend you not to use the **Kerberos** as **-Authentication**, you can use default since its a domain admin account.
- I believe the ports are open from the network side since you have already done that. But make sure to cross-check the state of the port; Its listening properly or not.

I believe these points will help you. Normally, VPN doesnot give this much issue unless the hops are really complicated.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and still have the same errors.

Comment: Then I believe , I have to understand the type of VPN you are using as well as how it has been implemented. It would be very much unfair to give any solution in generic.

Comment: I am using Cisco Anyconnect to a Cisco 5500 ASA. I have made sure the ports are allowed through and I seem to be hitting the server just fine which makes me think the issue is not with the VPN or firewall but I am at a loss as to what else may be the cause. It must be something simple to make this so hard to figure out!

Comment: @Pete : Sorry Pete, I can completely understand your concern. But I am at this point clueless about the environmental setup. 
If I would have sat on one of your environment's systems, then probably atleast we can check that. 
Could you please check the Authentication type.? Instead of Kerberos, please try other options also. 
And also recommend you to try with one of the Domain Accounts which has all the privileges.